# Extracting information from ICtab() function of bbmle

Tags: r

I'm having some trouble extracting information from the *ICtab()* function of the ***bbmle*** package. Essentially what I'm trying to do is run this function on a series of glm models, then add that output to a master data.frame object. However, while I can extract the $dqAIC and $df parameters from the *ICtab()* output, I cannot figure out a way to extract the row names themselves (i.e. the names of the models that are being input into ICtab). This is an issue because the *ICtab()* output is ordered in ascending order of $dqAIC - as such, I cannot pre-label a list or data.frame or matrix with the correct order, as the resulting $dqAIC values are not known ahead of time. To compound the problem, the *ICtab()* object class does not seem to be able to be coerced into a data.frame or any other object where I might be able to extract row.names() or anything similar.

What I'm looking for is a way to extract all the information from the *ICtab()* function, as a whole or in 3 pieces (row names, dqAIC values, and df values), and then append it to a master table along with some other information.

Below is a sample of the code I'm trying, along with some test data.

```
library(bbmle)
library(visreg)
library(splines)
library(foreign)
library(survival)
library(lubridate)

dfun<- function(object) {with(object, sum((weights*residuals^2)[weights>0])/df.residual)}  

test.data.1 <- seq(1, 1000, by = 10)
num.days <- seq(1, 100, by = 1)

disp.global <- glm(test.data.1 ~ num.days, family=poisson(link="log"), na.action=na.exclude)

model.1 <- glm(test.data.1 ~ ns(num.days, df = 3), family=poisson(link="log"), na.action=na.exclude)
model.2 <- glm(test.data.1 ~ ns(num.days, df = 6), family=poisson(link="log"), na.action=na.exclude)

testIC <- ICtab(model.1, model.2, dispersion=dfun(disp.global),type="qAIC")
```

Which gives the result:

```
> testIC
        dqAIC df
model.2 0     7 
model.1 5     4
```

I can pull the dqAIC and df values:

```
> testIC$dqAIC
[1] 0.000000 5.018875
> testIC$df
[1] 7 4
```

But I cannot figure out a way to get the "model.2" and "model.1" row names; *row.names(testIC)* returns nothing, and *rownames(testIC)* simply returns a NULL:

```
> row.names(testIC)
> rownames(testIC)
NULL
```

And as far as I can tell, there is no way to change this output using *list()*, *as.data.frame()*, *data.frame()*, or any other object type to get these row names.

```
> as.data.frame(testIC)
Error in as.data.frame.default(testIC) : 
  cannot coerce class ""ICtab"" to a data.frame
```

As a side note, in the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bbmle/bbmle.pdf) for the ***bbmle*** package, there appears to be a function called *get.mnames()* that should do exactly this - list the model names - however, it does not appear to be included in the ***bbmle*** package that is installed (my version matches the version of the documentation, 1.0.18):

```
> ls("package:bbmle")
 [1] "AIC"          "AICc"         "AICctab"      "AICtab"       "anova"        "BICtab"       "call.to.char" "coef"         "confint"      "deviance"    
[11] "formula"      "ICtab"        "logLik"       "mle2"         "namedrop"     "parnames"     "parnames<-"   "plot"         "predict"      "profile"     
[21] "qAIC"         "qAICc"        "relist2"      "residuals"    "sbeta"        "sbetabinom"   "sbinom"       "simulate"     "slice"        "slice1D"     
[31] "slice2D"      "sliceOld"     "snbinom"      "snorm"        "spois"        "stdEr"        "summary"      "update"       "vcov"
```

Any help getting these row names out of the ICtab() result would be greatly appreciated. The above code is simply a sample - what I'm actually doing is running multiple models, with a series of datasets, through the ICtab() function, and I want to put all of that information together in one data.frame object as the result.

Thanks in advance,

Nate

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem as yours, and I can see that nobody replied to your post.
I am not proud of my solution, it is not very elegant, but it works

```
class(testIC) <- "data.frame"
 rownames(testIC)
```

I hope it would help someone, someday.

Answer (score 0):

trantsyx' solution actually works fine. It can be combined with the convenient `table2office` [command](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/export/versions/0.3.0/topics/table2office) from package **export**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).